# How to change sitecore sxa rendering variants with powershell?

Tags: rendering, sitecore

I am working on a POC for a client project and facing challenge to change SXA variants for renderings in bulk. Any guidelines or recommenditions on how can I save my time by doing it in bulk?

I made the choice to develop a PowerShell script for the task at hand.

Despite my lack of prior experience in performing this specific task and my inability to locate the precise field that requires modification.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering Variant is stored in parameters with name 'FieldNames' in presentation XML.
Here is a sample rendering tag from presentation XML -

```
<r uid="{44670097-01D1-46CD-9035-4656087B6F74}" s:ds="local:/Data/Testing 01" s:id="{10BEBAE8-3FAA-4EDC-ADD7-B1453B72FAC8}" s:par="Reset Caching Options&amp;GridParameters=%7B908E2BC6-C110-4ED7-AF39-7EEACBB31A34%7D&amp;FieldNames=%7BE5EC7A66-8FF9-49AB-AF80-60361DDD82BC%7D&amp;Styles&amp;CacheClearingBehavior=Clear%20on%20publish&amp;RenderingIdentifier&amp;DynamicPlaceholderId=1" s:ph="/main/sxa-one-column/container-1" />
```

You would need to change it to desired variant id in presentation XML (Shared, Final or Standard Value depending on where it is set).

Here is an article for reference.

[Change SXA Rendering](https://www.altudo.co/insights/blogs/using-powershell-to-change-sitecore-sxa-rendering-variants)